# How to use namespaces to validate XML

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I'm trying to understand how to validate an XML document with multiple namespaces in it and not getting very far. As a simplified example of what I'm doing, I have a "root" element defined in one namespace like this:

**File:** "root.xsd"

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:complexType name="root"/>
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="root">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="allowedChild"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="allowedChild"/>
    <xs:element name="allowedChild" type="allowedChild"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Then a "child" element defined like this:

**File:** "child.xsd"

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="root.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="child">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="allowedChild"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="child" type="child" substitutionGroup="allowedChild"/>
</xs:schema>
```

And an xml that I'd like to validate that I think should look like this:

```
<root xmlns="root.xsd">
    <child xmlns="child.xsd"/>
</root>
```

If I try to validate this in XmlSpy I get "Unable to locate a reference to a supported schema type (DTD, W3C Schema) within this document instance.".

I also tried to write some C# to validate (that's my ultimate goal). My code looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var stream = new StreamReader("Example.xml"))
    {
        XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemaSet.ValidationEventHandler += MyValidationEventHandler;
        schemaSet.XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();

        schemaSet.Add(null, "root.xsd");

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings()
        {
            ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
            ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings,
            Schemas = schemaSet,
        };

        settings.ValidationEventHandler += MyValidationEventHandler;

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        }
    }
}

static void MyValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
}
```

but that gives me the following validation errors:

```
Could not find schema information for the element 'root.xsd:root'.
Could not find schema information for the element 'child.xsd:child'.
```

I was hoping that the XmlUrlResolver would find that xsd files (saved in the same folder), but I guess its not doing that???

My goal is to have multiple child.xsd type files, that are produced after compile time and resolved only at run time. Is this possible?

Comment: You need to use a `targetNamespace` in your schemas. Those namespaces are what you should reference in the `xmlns`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    targetNamespace="http://root.schemas.mycompany.com">

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    targetNamespace="http://child.schemas.mycompany.com">

<root xmlns="http://root.schemas.mycompany.com">
    <child xmlns="http://child.schemas.mycompany.com"/>
</root>
```

You are treating the XSD file name as a namespace name, which is not correct. Additionally, since you aren't using `targetNamespace`, your XML types and elements are not part of *any* namespace at all.

Comment: My child schema has an include for the root schema that now gives me the error: The included schema's target namespace 'http://root.schemas.mycompany.com' must be absent or match the including schema's value 'http://child.schemas.mycompany.com'.

Comment: I didn't notice the `include`, but it doesn't matter that much. The fact is that you have to decide which types and elements are in which namespace, and then your XML must reference the correct namespace. Note that this is not a .NET issue - you would get the same errors using XMLspy or any other XML validator.

Comment: I think I'm nearly there... I changed the include to an import and that seems to be working better.